# Difference between Samsara and Dukkha

Tags: samsara, dukkha

What is the difference between the terms "samsara" and "dukkha"?

What is the relationship between the two?

Comment: Dukkha means that your life sucks. Samsara means, so will your next one, (and your next one, and your ... repeat until enlightened)  :-)

Comment: Saṃsāra is the house that Avijja (ignorance) built. It rests on three pillars anicca, anatta and dukkha, also known as the three marks of existence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Samsara is a continuum of our  individual mind moments.

Dukkha is the deep down feeling that something is missing or wrong that occurs throughout Samsara.

Answer (score 3):

In my own words:

*Samsara* is the same world you see on TV and read about in newspapers. This world is a hallucination (a subjective reality) fabricated in dependence on the fundamental confusion caused by the fundamental ignorance. This confusion causes *dukkha* and *dukkha* causes further confusion, which is why Samsara is dubbed "cyclic existence" - but also because the confusion is passed on from previous lives to future lives.

*Dukkha* is the painful and bitter feeling of wrongness you experience while in Samsara, because of the mismatch between the hallucination and reality.

Comment: Sorry to complain but are you saying that, "Buddhism says that the world is an illusion or a hallucination"? If so I've 'always' thought that's a too-simplistic (not helpful or prescriptive) description. Also if I don't watch TV it isn't clear what else (apart from the world on TV) samsara is or isn't.

Comment: not literally, no. Though "hallucination" is the exact word my Zen Master used -- and I used to hate it myself... but the more I share what I was taught the more I appreciate the brightly metaphorical pointers over the tedious conceptual expositions. I did mention "subjective reality" parenthetically to add a little more depth to the metaphor, it is pretty subtle one.

Comment: To try to help clarify, perhaps, my Eastern Philosophies professor told us that the Hindu concept of Samara is based on _delusion_, where the individual misperceives the external reality. The example Hindu theologians use is a coiled rope that appears to be a snake in the dark --it's a misperception. Whereas the Buddhist idea of Samsara is based on _illusion_, where an individual projects qualities originating in their own mind (ideas of good and bad, permanence, etc) onto the external world.

Comment: @user151841 - yes, this is pretty close

Answer (score 0):

Saṃsāra is endless cyclic existence (*Anamataggo bhikkawe samsaro pubbha kota na pannayati*) caused by Avijja and Tanha (*Avijja neevarananang thanha sanyojanag*). Note that Avijja means ignorance about four noble truths including Dukkha.

[Avijja Sutta -SN 45](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.001.than.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dukkha not only means suffering but means breakable, changing, fragile, breaking, falling apart, changes, stressful etc..   it is clearer with buddha quote "all Vedana [feelings; pleasurable, suffering, or equanimity] end with Dukkha.  So dukkha is a property of those who are traveling in Samsara

Answer (score 0):

Others have nicely explained the different meanings of the two terms. As for their relationship, I'd actually say that *samsara* and *dukkha* are the same thing from different perspectives -- samsara from a cosmological standpoint, dukkha from an individual (psychological) standpoint.

To be in samsara is to experience pervasive, self-reinforcing (cyclic) dukkha due to ignorance. To be in ignorance is to suffer and hence to be in samsara. So samsara => dukkha and dukkha => samsara, hence samsara <=> dukkha.

This is an elementary example of how cosmology and psychology (phenomenology, experience) mirror each other. Rupert Gethin treats this at some length in a great series of papers, though with more intricate concepts. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83s%C4%81ra_%28Buddhism%29#Equivalence_of_cosmology_and_psychology) it is summarized in the Wikipedia article on samsara. You can look up his papers on the subject, and he also treats it in chapter 5 of his text, [*The Foundations of Buddhism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=al_Wlh2mwWIC).

You could also add *avidya* (ignorance) as a third element of the equivalence, perhaps from the philosophical or conceptual perspective.

Answer (score 0):

They are conjoined in the dispensation:

what is samsara is dukkha, cessation of dukkha is cessation of samara and dukkha is a characteristic of samsara.

analogy:

What is water is liquid, cessation of liquid is cessation of water and liquid is a characteristic of water.

It would not be appropriate to use them as synonyms always as they are different abstractions.